# How to set this break-even stop loss to trigger immediately

Tags: pine-script

explanation

[image: 1]

I've studied the Trailing stop loss system and found this module in Tradingview.
My goal is where the price reaches my TP setup (which is 80% for example) I want to take my profit and put the break-even to the entry price immediately to prevent some loss.

It works partially well.
The problem in this module executed the remaining position not immediately. Even if the price once reached TP and dropped to the entry price(break-even) in the same bar
It delays execution to the next bar. Any Hints or solutions would be appreciated.

`

```
//@version=5
//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ 
//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Copyright 2022 Iason Nikolas | jason5480
//  Trailing Take Profit Trailing Stop Loss script may be freely distributed under the MIT license.
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, 
//  to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), 
//  to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, 
//  publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, 
//  subject to the following conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, 
//  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, 
//  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, 
//  DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, 
//  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//
//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Authors:  @jason5480
//  Revision: v2.5.0
//  Date:     01-Sep-2022
//
//  Description
//  =============================================================================
//  This strategy will go long if fast MA crosses over slow MA.
//  The strategy will exit from long position when the price increases by a fixed percentage.
//  If the trailing take profit is checked then the strategy instead of setting a limit order in a predefined price (based on the percentage)
//  it will follow the price with small steps (percentagewise)
//  If the price drops by this percentage then the exit order will be executed
//  
//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Disclaimer:
//    1. I am not licensed financial advisors or broker dealer. I do not tell you 
//       when or what to buy or sell. I developed this software which enables you 
//       execute manual or automated trades using TradingView. The 
//       software allows you to set the criteria you want for entering and exiting 
//       trades.
//    2. Do not trade with money you cannot afford to lose.
//    3. I do not guarantee consistent profits or that anyone can make money with no 
//       effort. And I am not selling the holy grail.
//    4. Every system can have winning and losing streaks.
//    5. Money management plays a large role in the results of your trading. For 
//       example: lot size, account size, broker leverage, and broker margin call 
//       rules all have an effect on results. Also, your Take Profit and Stop Loss 
//       settings for individual pair trades and for overall account equity have a 
//       major impact on results. If you are new to trading and do not understand 
//       these items, then I recommend you seek education materials to further your
//       knowledge.
//
//    YOU NEED TO FIND AND USE THE TRADING SYSTEM THAT WORKS BEST FOR YOU AND YOUR 
//    TRADING TOLERANCE.
//
//    I HAVE PROVIDED NOTHING MORE THAN A TOOL WITH OPTIONS FOR YOU TO TRADE WITH THIS PROGRAM ON TRADINGVIEW.
//    
//    I accept suggestions to improve the script.
//    If you encounter any problems I will be happy to share with me.
//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// SETUP ============================================================================================================
strategy(title = 'Trailing Take Profit Trailing Stop Loss',
         shorttitle = 'TTPTSL',
         overlay = true,
         pyramiding = 0,
         default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity,
         default_qty_value = 100,
         initial_capital = 100000,
         max_lines_count = 150,
         max_labels_count = 300)

//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// FILTERS ==========================================================================================================

import jason5480/time_filters/5 as tif

// INPUT ============================================================================================================
src_timezone = input.string(defval = 'Exchange', title = 'Timezones Src->Dst', options = ['Exchange', 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Phoenix', 'America/Vancouver', 'America/El_Salvador', 'America/Bogota', 'America/Chicago', 'America/New_York', 'America/Toronto', 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires', 'America/Sao_Paulo', 'Etc/UTC', 'Europe/London', 'Europe/Berlin', 'Europe/Madrid', 'Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Warsaw', 'Europe/Athens', 'Europe/Moscow', 'Asia/Tehran', 'Asia/Dubai', 'Asia/Ashkhabad', 'Asia/Kolkata', 'Asia/Almaty', 'Asia/Bangkok', 'Asia/Hong_Kong', 'Asia/Shanghai', 'Asia/Singapore', 'Asia/Taipei', 'Asia/Seoul', 'Asia/Tokyo', 'Australia/ACT', 'Australia/Adelaide', 'Australia/Brisbane', 'Australia/Sydney', 'Pacific/Auckland', 'Pacific/Fakaofo', 'Pacific/Chatham', 'Pacific/Honolulu'], inline = 'Timezone', group = 'Filters')
dst_timezone = input.string(defval = 'Exchange', title = '->', options = ['Exchange', 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Phoenix', 'America/Vancouver', 'America/El_Salvador', 'America/Bogota', 'America/Chicago', 'America/New_York', 'America/Toronto', 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires', 'America/Sao_Paulo', 'Etc/UTC', 'Europe/London', 'Europe/Berlin', 'Europe/Madrid', 'Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Warsaw', 'Europe/Athens', 'Europe/Moscow', 'Asia/Tehran', 'Asia/Dubai', 'Asia/Ashkhabad', 'Asia/Kolkata', 'Asia/Almaty', 'Asia/Bangkok', 'Asia/Hong_Kong', 'Asia/Shanghai', 'Asia/Singapore', 'Asia/Taipei', 'Asia/Seoul', 'Asia/Tokyo', 'Australia/ACT', 'Australia/Adelaide', 'Australia/Brisbane', 'Australia/Sydney', 'Pacific/Auckland', 'Pacific/Fakaofo', 'Pacific/Chatham', 'Pacific/Honolulu'], tooltip = 'Source is the timezone to be used as a reference for the time settings. Destination is the timezone to convert into (e.g. the charts\' timezone)', inline = 'Timezone', group = 'Filters')

usefromDate = input.bool(defval = true, title = 'From', inline = "From Date", group = "Filters")
fromDate = input.time(defval = timestamp('01 Jan 2022 00:00'), title = '', inline = "From Date", group = 'Filters')
usetoDate = input.bool(defval = false, title = 'To ', inline = "To Date", group = "Filters")
toDate = input.time(defval = timestamp('01 Jul 2022 00:00'), title = '', inline = "To Date", group = 'Filters')

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
bool dateFilterApproval = tif.is_in_date_range(usefromDate, fromDate, usetoDate, toDate, src_timezone, dst_timezone)

// PLOT =============================================================================================================
bgcolor(color = dateFilterApproval ? na : color.new(color.gray, 90), title = 'Time Window')

//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// STRATEGY =========================================================================================================

// INPUT ============================================================================================================
longDealsEnabled = input.bool(defval = true, title = 'Long Deals', inline = 'Long/Short Deals', group = 'Strategy')
shortDealsEnabled = input.bool(defval = true, title = 'Short Deals', tooltip = 'Enable long/short deals. An open signal will be emited when the long/short start deal conditions are met. If this option is un-checked you will not enter into long/short positions.', inline = 'Long/Short Deals', group = 'Strategy')

fastMALen = input.int(defval = 21, title = 'Fast/Slow SMA Length', minval = 1, inline = 'MA Length', group = 'Strategy')
slowMALen = input.int(defval = 49, title = '', minval = 1, tooltip = 'How many candles back to calculte the fast/slow SMA.', inline = 'MA Length', group = 'Strategy')

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
float fastMA = ta.sma(close, fastMALen)
float slowMA = ta.sma(close, slowMALen)

bool crossover = ta.crossover(fastMA, slowMA)
bool crossunder = ta.crossunder(fastMA, slowMA)

bool openLongPosition = longDealsEnabled and dateFilterApproval and crossover
bool openShortPosition = shortDealsEnabled and dateFilterApproval and crossunder

bool closeLongPosition = longDealsEnabled and crossunder
bool closeShortPosition = shortDealsEnabled and crossover

// PLOT =============================================================================================================
var fastColor = color.new(color.yellow, 0)
plot(series = fastMA, title = 'Fast SMA', color = fastColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_line)
var slowColor = color.new(color.orange, 0)
plot(series = slowMA, title = 'Slow SMA', color = slowColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_line)

//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// ENTRY ============================================================================================================

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
// the open signals when not already into a position
bool validOpenLongPosition = openLongPosition and not (strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) > 0)
bool validOpenShortPosition = openShortPosition and not (strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) < 0)

bool longIsActive = validOpenLongPosition or strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) > 0 and not closeLongPosition
bool shortIsActive = validOpenShortPosition or strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) < 0 and not closeShortPosition

// PLOT =============================================================================================================
var longEntryColor = color.new(#2962FF, 0)
var shortEntryColor = color.new(#FF1744, 0)
var textColor = color.new(color.white, 0)
if (validOpenLongPosition)
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, text = 'Open', yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = longEntryColor, style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = textColor)
if (validOpenShortPosition)
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, text = 'Close', yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = shortEntryColor, style = label.style_label_down, textcolor = textColor)

//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// SHARED VARIABLES =================================================================================================

// INPUT ============================================================================================================
atrLength = input.int(defval = 14, title = 'ATR Length', minval = 1, tooltip = 'How many previous candles to use for the ATR calculation.', group = 'General')

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
// take profit has to communicate its execution with the stop loss logic when 'TP' mode is selected
var bool longTrailingTakeProfitExecuted = false
var bool shortTrailingTakeProfitExecuted = false

float openAtr = ta.valuewhen(validOpenLongPosition or validOpenShortPosition, ta.atr(atrLength), 0)

//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// STOP LOSS ========================================================================================================

// INPUT ============================================================================================================
stopLossMethod = input.string(defval = 'PERC', title = 'Stop Loss Method', options = ['PERC', 'ATR'], tooltip = 'The method to calculate the Stop Loss (percentagewise, based on initial ATR or based on ATR changing over time).', group = 'Stop Loss - Target')
longTrailingStopLossPerc = input.float(defval = 7.5, title = 'Long/Short Stop Loss %', minval = 0.05, maxval = 100, step = 0.05, inline = 'Trailing Stop Loss Perc', group = 'Stop Loss - Target') / 100
shortTrailingStopLossPerc = input.float(defval = 7.5, title = '', minval = 0.05, maxval = 100, step = 0.05, tooltip = 'The percentage of the price decrease/increase to set the Stop Loss price target for long/short positions.', inline = 'Trailing Stop Loss Perc', group = 'Stop Loss - Target') / 100
longStopLossAtrMul = input.float(defval = 3.0, title = 'ATR Long/Short Mul ', minval = 0.1, step = 0.1, inline = 'Trailing Stop Loss ATR Multiplier', group = 'Stop Loss - Target')
shortStopLossAtrMul = input.float(defval = 3.0, title = '', minval = 0.1, step = 0.1, tooltip = 'ATR multiplier to be used for the long/short Stop Loss.', inline = 'Trailing Stop Loss ATR Multiplier', group = 'Stop Loss - Target')
stopLossTrailingEnabled = input.string(defval = 'TP', title = 'Enable Trailing', options = ['TP', 'ON', 'OFF'], tooltip = 'Enable the trailing for Stop Loss when Take Profit order is executed (TP) or from the start of the entry order (ON) or not at all (OFF).', group = 'Stop Loss - Trailing')
breakEvenEnabled = input.bool(defval = false, title = 'Break Even', tooltip = 'When Take Profit price target is hit, move the Stop Loss to the entry price (or to a more strict price defined by the Stop Loss %/ATR Multiplier).', group = 'Stop Loss - Trailing')

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
getLongStopLossPrice(baseSrc) =>
    switch stopLossMethod
        'PERC' => baseSrc * (1 - longTrailingStopLossPerc)
        'ATR' => baseSrc - longStopLossAtrMul * openAtr
        => na
    
// trailing starts when the take profit price is reached if 'TP' mode is set or from the very begining if 'ON' mode is selected
bool longTakeProfitTrailingEnabled = stopLossTrailingEnabled == 'ON' or stopLossTrailingEnabled == 'TP' and longTrailingTakeProfitExecuted

// calculate trailing stop loss price when enter long position and peserve its value until the position closes
var float longStopLossPrice = na
longStopLossPrice := if (longIsActive)
    if (validOpenLongPosition)
        getLongStopLossPrice(close)
    else
        stopPrice = getLongStopLossPrice(longTakeProfitTrailingEnabled ? high : strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1))
        stopPrice := breakEvenEnabled and longTrailingTakeProfitExecuted ? math.max(stopPrice, strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)) : stopPrice
        math.max(stopPrice, nz(longStopLossPrice[1]))
else
    na

getShortStopLossPrice(baseSrc) =>
    switch stopLossMethod
        'PERC' => baseSrc * (1 + shortTrailingStopLossPerc)
        'ATR' => baseSrc + shortStopLossAtrMul * openAtr
        => na

// trailing starts when the take profit price is reached if 'TP' mode is set or from the very begining if 'ON' mode is selected
bool shortTakeProfitTrailingEnabled = stopLossTrailingEnabled == 'ON' or stopLossTrailingEnabled == 'TP' and shortTrailingTakeProfitExecuted

// calculate trailing stop loss price when enter short position and peserve its value until the position closes
var float shortStopLossPrice = na
shortStopLossPrice := if (shortIsActive)
    if (validOpenShortPosition)
        getShortStopLossPrice(close)
    else
        stopPrice = getShortStopLossPrice(shortTakeProfitTrailingEnabled ? low : strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1))
        stopPrice := breakEvenEnabled and shortTrailingTakeProfitExecuted ? math.min(stopPrice, strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)) : stopPrice
        math.min(stopPrice, nz(shortStopLossPrice[1], 999999.9))
else
    na

// PLOT =============================================================================================================
var stopLossColor = color.new(color.maroon, 0)
plot(series = longStopLossPrice, title = 'Long Stop Loss', color = stopLossColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)
plot(series = shortStopLossPrice, title = 'Short Stop Loss', color = stopLossColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)

//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// TAKE PROFIT ======================================================================================================

// INPUT ============================================================================================================
takeProfitQuantityPerc = input.float(defval = 50, title = 'Take Profit Quantity %', minval = 0.0, maxval = 100, step = 1.0, tooltip = 'The percentage of the position that will be withdrawn when the take profit price target is reached.', group = 'Take Profit - Quantity')

takeProfitMethod = input.string(defval = 'PERC', title = 'Take Profit Method', options = ['PERC', 'ATR', 'RR'], tooltip = 'The method to calculate the Take Profit price.', group = 'Take Profit - Target')
longTakeProfitPerc = input.float(defval = 10.0, title = 'Long/Short Take Profit %', minval = 0.05, step = 0.05, inline = 'Take Profit Perc', group = 'Take Profit - Target') / 100
shortTakeProfitPerc = input.float(defval = 10.0, title = '', minval = 0.05, step = 0.05, tooltip = 'The percentage of the price increase/decrease to set the take profit price target for long/short positions.', inline = 'Take Profit Perc', group = 'Take Profit - Target') / 100
longTakeProfitAtrMul = input.float(defval = 9.0, title = 'ATR Long/Short Mul ', minval = 0.1, step = 0.1, inline = 'Take Profit ATR Multiplier', group = 'Take Profit - Target')
shortTakeProfitAtrMul = input.float(defval = 9.0, title = '', minval = 0.1, step = 0.1, tooltip = 'ATR multiplier to be used for the long/short Take Profit.', inline = 'Take Profit ATR Multiplier', group = 'Take Profit - Target')
longRiskRewardRatio = input.float(defval = 1.5, title = 'Long/Short RR Ratio ', minval = 0.1, step = 0.1, inline = 'Risk Reward Ratio', group = 'Take Profit - Target')
shortRiskRewardRatio = input.float(defval = 1.5, title = '', minval = 0.1, step = 0.1, tooltip = 'The Risk/Reward Ratio to be used for the long/short Take Profit based on the Stop Loss Price.', inline = 'Risk Reward Ratio', group = 'Take Profit - Target')

takeProfitTrailingEnabled = input.bool(defval = true, title = 'Enable Trailing', tooltip = 'Enable or disable the trailing for take profit.', group = 'Take Profit - Trailing')
deviationMethod = input.string(defval = 'PERC', title = 'Deviation Method', options = ['PERC', 'ATR'], tooltip = 'The method to calculate the Deviation for the Trailing Take Profit.', group = 'Take Profit - Trailing')
deviationPerc = input.float(defval = 1.0, title = 'Deviation %', minval = 0.01, maxval = 100, step = 0.05, tooltip = 'The percentage wise step to be used for following the price, when the take profit target is reached.', group = 'Take Profit - Trailing') / 100
deviationAtrMul = input.float(defval = 1.0, title = 'Deviation ATR Mul', minval = 0.01, step = 0.05, tooltip = 'Multiplier to be used on the initial entrys` ATR to calculate the step for following the price, when the take profit target is reached.', group = 'Take Profit - Trailing')

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
getLongTakeProfitPrice() =>
    switch takeProfitMethod
        'PERC' => close * (1 + longTakeProfitPerc)
        'ATR' => close + longTakeProfitAtrMul * openAtr
        'RR' => close + longRiskRewardRatio * (close - getLongStopLossPrice(close))
        => na

getLongTakeProfitPerc() =>
    (close - getLongTakeProfitPrice()) / close

// calculate take profit price when enter long position and peserve its value until the position closes
var float longTakeProfitPrice = na
longTakeProfitPrice := if (longIsActive and not longTrailingTakeProfitExecuted)
    if (validOpenLongPosition)
        getLongTakeProfitPrice()
    else
        nz(longTakeProfitPrice[1], getLongTakeProfitPrice())
else
    na

longTrailingTakeProfitExecuted := strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) > 0 and (longTrailingTakeProfitExecuted[1] or strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) < strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1)[1] or strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1)[1] == 0 and high >= longTakeProfitPrice)

longTrailingTakeProfitStepTicks = switch deviationMethod
    'PERC' => longTakeProfitPrice * deviationPerc / syminfo.mintick
    'ATR' => deviationAtrMul * openAtr / syminfo.mintick
    => na

getShortTakeProfitPrice() =>
    switch takeProfitMethod
        'PERC' => close * (1 - shortTakeProfitPerc)
        'ATR' => close - shortTakeProfitAtrMul * openAtr
        'RR' => close - shortRiskRewardRatio * (getShortStopLossPrice(close) - close)
        => na

getShortTakeProfitPerc() =>
    (getShortTakeProfitPrice() - close) / close

// calculate take profit price when enter short position and peserve its value until the position closes
var float shortTakeProfitPrice = na
shortTakeProfitPrice := if (shortIsActive and not shortTrailingTakeProfitExecuted)
    if (validOpenShortPosition)
        getShortTakeProfitPrice()
    else
        nz(shortTakeProfitPrice[1], getShortTakeProfitPrice())
else
    na

shortTrailingTakeProfitExecuted := strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) < 0 and (shortTrailingTakeProfitExecuted[1] or strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) > strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1)[1] or strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1)[1] == 0 and low <= shortTakeProfitPrice)

shortTrailingTakeProfitStepTicks = switch deviationMethod
    'PERC' => shortTakeProfitPrice * deviationPerc / syminfo.mintick
    'ATR' => deviationAtrMul * openAtr / syminfo.mintick
    => na

// PLOT =============================================================================================================
var takeProfitColor = color.new(color.teal, 0)
plot(series = longTakeProfitPrice, title = 'Long Take Profit', color = takeProfitColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)
plot(series = shortTakeProfitPrice, title = 'Short Take Profit', color = takeProfitColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = 1)

//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// POSITION ORDERS ==================================================================================================

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
// close on trend reversal
if (closeLongPosition)
    strategy.close(id = 'Long Entry', comment = 'Close Long', alert_message = 'Long: Closed at market price')

// close on trend reversal
if (closeShortPosition)
    strategy.close(id = 'Short Entry', comment = 'Close Short', alert_message = 'Short: Closed at market price')

// getting into LONG position
if (validOpenLongPosition)
    strategy.entry(id = 'Long Entry', direction = strategy.long, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Started')

// submit exit order for trailing take profit price also set the stop loss for the take profit percentage in case that stop loss is reached first
// submit exit order for trailing stop loss price for the remaining percent of the quantity not reserved by the take profit order
if (longIsActive)
    strategy.exit(id = 'Long Take Profit / Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Long Entry', qty_percent = takeProfitQuantityPerc, limit = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? na : longTakeProfitPrice, stop = longStopLossPrice, trail_price = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? longTakeProfitPrice : na, trail_offset = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? longTrailingTakeProfitStepTicks : na, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Take Profit or Stop Loss executed')
    strategy.exit(id = 'Long Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Long Entry', stop = longStopLossPrice, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Stop Loss executed')

// getting into SHORT position
if (validOpenShortPosition)
    strategy.entry(id = 'Short Entry', direction = strategy.short, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Started')

// submit exit order for trailing take profit price also set the stop loss for the take profit percentage in case that stop loss is reached first
// submit exit order for trailing stop loss price for the remaining percent of the quantity not reserved by the take profit order
if (shortIsActive)
    strategy.exit(id = 'Short Take Profit / Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Short Entry', qty_percent = takeProfitQuantityPerc, limit = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? na : shortTakeProfitPrice, stop = shortStopLossPrice, trail_price = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? shortTakeProfitPrice : na, trail_offset = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? shortTrailingTakeProfitStepTicks : na, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Take Profit or Stop Loss executed')
    strategy.exit(id = 'Short Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Short Entry', stop = shortStopLossPrice, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Stop Loss executed')

// PLOT =============================================================================================================
var posColor = color.new(color.white, 0)
plot(series = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1), title = 'Position', color = posColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_linebr)

// ==================================================================================================================
```

`

I've tried this code.

```
var float SL2 = na
var bool  LS  = na
var bool  SS  = na

LS := longDealsEnabled or strategy.position_size > 0
SS := shortDealsEnabled or strategy.position_size < 0


if LS and high > longTakeProfitPrice 
    if open <= longTakeProfitPrice  
        SL2 := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)

if SS and low < shortTakeProfitPrice 
    if open >= shortTakeProfitPrice
        SL2 := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
```

And add this SL2 to exit it. But nothing changed.

```
strategy.exit(id = 'Break-even', from_entry = 'Short Entry', stop = SL2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried and solved this With https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029126/19373198 Answered code by Hernán Orsi.

Here is the solution if it helps anyone! Add this to the end exit condition.

**Before**

```
if (longIsActive)
    strategy.exit(id = 'Long Take Profit / Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Long Entry', qty_percent = takeProfitQuantityPerc, limit = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? na : longTakeProfitPrice, stop = longStopLossPrice, trail_price = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? longTakeProfitPrice : na, trail_offset = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? longTrailingTakeProfitStepTicks : na, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Take Profit or Stop Loss executed')
    strategy.exit(id = 'Long Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Long Entry', stop = longStopLossPrice, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Stop Loss executed')

// getting into SHORT position
if (validOpenShortPosition)
    strategy.entry(id = 'Short Entry', direction = strategy.short, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Started')

// submit exit order for trailing take profit price also set the stop loss for the take profit percentage in case that stop loss is reached first
// submit exit order for trailing stop loss price for the remaining percent of the quantity not reserved by the take profit order
if (shortIsActive)
    strategy.exit(id = 'Short Take Profit / Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Short Entry', qty_percent = takeProfitQuantityPerc, limit = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? na : shortTakeProfitPrice, stop = shortStopLossPrice, trail_price = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? shortTakeProfitPrice : na, trail_offset = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? shortTrailingTakeProfitStepTicks : na, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Take Profit or Stop Loss executed')
    strategy.exit(id = 'Short Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Short Entry', stop = shortStopLossPrice, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Stop Loss executed')
```

**After**

```
if (longIsActive)
    strategy.exit(id = 'Long Take Profit / Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Long Entry', qty_percent = takeProfitQuantityPerc, limit = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? na : longTakeProfitPrice, stop = longStopLossPrice, trail_price = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? longTakeProfitPrice : na, trail_offset = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? longTrailingTakeProfitStepTicks : na, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Take Profit or Stop Loss executed')
    strategy.exit(id = 'Long Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Long Entry', stop = longStopLossPrice, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Stop Loss executed')
    strategy.close_all(stcDownBreakouts)

if(ta.change(strategy.closedtrades) and strategy.openprofit > 0)
    strategy.cancel('Long Stop Loss')
    breakEven = (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0))
    strategy.exit(id = 'Long Stop - Breakeven', from_entry = 'Long Entry', loss=0)

// getting into SHORT position
if (validOpenShortPosition)
    strategy.entry(id = 'Short Entry', direction = strategy.short, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Started')

// submit exit order for trailing take profit price also set the stop loss for the take profit percentage in case that stop loss is reached first
// submit exit order for trailing stop loss price for the remaining percent of the quantity not reserved by the take profit order
if (shortIsActive)
    strategy.exit(id = 'Short Take Profit / Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Short Entry', qty_percent = takeProfitQuantityPerc, limit = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? na : shortTakeProfitPrice, stop = shortStopLossPrice, trail_price = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? shortTakeProfitPrice : na, trail_offset = takeProfitTrailingEnabled ? shortTrailingTakeProfitStepTicks : na, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Take Profit or Stop Loss executed')
    strategy.exit(id = 'Short Stop Loss', from_entry = 'Short Entry', stop = shortStopLossPrice, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Stop Loss executed')
    strategy.close_all(stcUpBreakouts)

if(ta.change(strategy.closedtrades) and strategy.openprofit > 0)
    strategy.cancel('Short Stop Loss')
    breakEven = (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0))
    strategy.exit(id = 'Short Stop - Breakeven', from_entry = 'Short Entry', loss=0)
```